# PhantomJS is not loading scripts correctly from html page with tests

Tags: teamcity, phantomjs

PhantomJS is not loading scripts, because it tries to load them at the following path: file:///[src specified in html file]. In html file the paths to the scripts is relative, and I do not want to make them absolute (was doing following this example http://thomasardal.com/tag/phantomjs/). So, for example in html page I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.0.js"></script>` and PhantomJS tries to load it from file:///jquery-1.7.0.js which is not exists. How to get make PhantomJS load scripts from the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue and would seem like a bug in phantomjs.

Found one way to get around the issue:

Inside your page.open function you can call page.injectJs(FILENAME) - and FILENAME would appear to work with a path relative from the execution path or page.libraryPath (which defaults to where the first js arg is located)

Comment: well, I would like to have separate html files for separate module tests, and to keep js which loads these pages as generic as possible. I found similar way: catching onResourceRequested, the parameter is the request, which keeps the url of the request, then I'm calling injectJs function, providing path as libraryPath+request.url. but still looks hacky(

Comment: I tried with resourceRequested when loading html from file using a relative url but it was never called :-( I switched to jasmine which does not need a browser (and as a personal note, has better syntax). This was a good fit for me since the js is not really that dependent on dom-manipulations.. so only used injectJs and that worked fine and was as easy to plugin to teamcity

Comment: There are threads on the phantomjs for these issues that might be worth to follow: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=330&q=relative%20url and http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=171&can=8